# IAM policy for AWS S3 complete access on all buckets the user creates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, amazon-iam

How should IAM inline policy for an IAM user should be so that the user can perform all actions on all buckets the user creates, but should not be able to have any access on buckets other user creates.